# Custom Theme is ignored after move to production server

Tags: magento2, theme, static-content-deploy, production-mode, custom-theme

I recently moved my **Magento 2.2.3** site to production server (different server, url and path). However, the custom theme seems to be ignored. If I enter the site, it shows the following error in the **var/report** files:

> Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed
>   /.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Fallback/Rule/Theme.php(78):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Design\Fallback\Rule\Simple->getPatternDirs(Array)

Some people in some threads said that this error is throw where the theme directory is deleted, but the directory is present in the same path of develop. And if I try to run:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Vendor/theme es_MX en_US -f

Nothing happens. The strange thing is that it only happens with our custom theme child that we did. The father theme and his other children work without problem.

What could it be?

Comment: Look into the database table which stores the themes. I think your theme is missing there.

Comment: The theme is in theme table.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that you have a theme configured which doesn't exist on the file-system (anymore), but the DB entry was still there in theme table.

To fix the problem, go to your **theme** table and delete the entry for your created theme.

Then go to your **`core_config_data`** table and search for the theme and you will get path records like **`design/theme/theme_id`** replace your default theme id in it.

Comment: Thanks fot your comment, but the theme files are present in app/design/fontend directory and in theme table.

Comment: Okay, then please share the solution to your problem, so that others can get the benefit.